# Facebook authentication response parameters are wrong -> infinite request loop

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, sdk

I an new to the facebook API and after some work I encountered a problem.
First, I am using [the facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/documentation) for communication with the facebook APIs.

In my app settings I chose that the response of the OAuth dialog should be query string instead of URI fragment.

[image]

On my server I got the following code:

```
void Page_Load()
{
    string url = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    Facebook.FacebookOAuthResult result = null;        
    if (!Facebook.FacebookOAuthResult.TryParse(url, out result))
    {
        string redirectUrl = PivotServer.Helpers.GetFacebookOAuthUrl();
        Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
    }
}
```

And thats my helper method:

```
    public static string GetFacebookOAuthUrl()
    {
        FacebookOAuthClient oauth = new FacebookOAuthClient
        {
            AppId = "149637255147166",
            AppSecret = "xxx",
            RedirectUri = new Uri("http://mydomain.com/")
        };

        var param = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "response_type", "token" },
            { "display", "popup" }
        };

        Uri url = oauth.GetLoginUrl(param);

        return url.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

I ran my page on a web server (IIS). When I open the page the first time I am asked to log in to facebook, which is alright, but then I ran into an infinity loop, because the Auth Token Parameter (from facebook) is an URI fragment instead if a query string (which I wanted (see picture above)).
The response URI looks like

`http://mydomain.com/#access_token=AAACIGCNwLp4BAMccSoliF5EMGJm0NPldv5GpmBPIm9z7rRuSkiia7BM0uhEn1V88c8uOlWOfGc3C8sFC9tq90Ma0OwIm0tWLNU5BBAZDZD&expires_in=0&base_domain=mydomain.com`

instead of

`http://mydomain.com/?code=AAACIGCNwLp4BAMccSoliF5EMGJm0NPldv5GpmBPIm9z7rRuSkiia7BM0uhEn1V88c8uOlWOfGc3C8sFC9tq90Ma0OwIm0tWLNU5BBAZDZD&expires_in=0&base_domain=mydomain.com`

Is that a bug from the OAuth API, or what am I doing very wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been too easy:

```
var param = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "response_type", "code" }, // <--- "code" instead of "token"
    { "display", "popup" }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with IE. Be sure to have a p3p header in each response from your server.